# Placing iAD banner always at the bottom of the screen(IOS 7)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios7, iad

So I am implementing the singleton iAD system and I got the function that adds the banner on the view, but how can I make sure that the banner is always on the bottom so it works with both 3.5inch and 4inch screen?

Here is my code but the banner won't position correctly, it goes off screen

```
-(void)attachBannerToViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{

    if (_iAdBanner == nil) {
        NSLog(@"iAdbanner alloc");
        _iAdBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        _iAdBanner.delegate = self;
        _iAdBanner.alpha = 0.0;
    }

    CGRect frame=CGRectZero;
    frame.size = _iAdBanner.frame.size;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, viewController.view.frame.size.height-_iAdBanner.frame.size.height);

    [_iAdBanner setFrame:frame];
    [viewController.view addSubview:_iAdBanner];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say you are running this code before you view controller has finished all it's setup. When you run this line of code it will be correct, but by the time the `view controller.view` gets added to the `window` it will be wrong.

Consider setting up your auto-resizing flags or constraints to keep the ad banner in the correct position. Which are you using?

`_iAdBanner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`

Constraints.... someone else just posted and answer for setting it up with constraints so I won't duplicate their work. :)

Comment: If you're going to use an autoresizing mask, you may want to also give it flexible width, so that it fills the full width of the view controller

Comment: While that would be a usually be an appropriate thing to do, it adds extra complexity to the answer and does something which not requested and possibly not even desired. Should the person wish that behavior the code bit provided would most likely have given them enough information to tweak the line for other desired behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
-(void)attachBannerToViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    if (_iAdBanner == nil) {
        NSLog(@"iAdbanner alloc");
        _iAdBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        _iAdBanner.delegate = self;
        _iAdBanner.alpha = 0.0;
        _iAdBanner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [viewController.view addSubview:_iAdBanner];
        [viewController.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint
          constrainsWithVisualFormat:@"|-0-[banner]-0-|"
          options:0
          metrics:nil
          views:@{"banner" : _iAdBanner}]];
        [viewController.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint
          constrainsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[banner]-0-|"
          options:0
          metrics:nil
          views:@{"banner" : _iAdBanner}]];
    }
}
```